# How do I assign a sql record value to string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm new to asp, so be patient :p

I have an sql database, with a users table that has username and a colour.

My asp master page is reading the current users username and passing it to the content fine.
What I am trying to now do is in the content page grab the colour from the sql table where the username is the current username, and assign it to a string inside the default.aspx.cs file.

How do I do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

From your comments, your question is about how to read a value from SQL Server.  The most basic way is by just opening a SqlConnection, create a SqlCommand, setting the command text, etc etc.  There are many tutorials online.  Unfortunately you run the risk of Sql Injection attacks that way.

The best way is to set up an OR Mapper, which creates objects for you, that map directly to your database.  The best option there would probably be Entity Framework 4.  There are plenty of tutorials online.

**END EDIT**

Probably the best thing to do would be to set a property in your master page, and then have your default.aspx page read the value from the master page, and do whatever it wants with it.

Having said that, it's usually a bad idea to be doing database reads from your UI.  Usually you'll want to push that stuff off to another tier, and have your UI focus on just doing UI things.

But, assuming this is just a simple project, then something like the following line should get you where you need to go:

From default.aspx:

```
string value = (this.Master as YourMasterPageClass).YourProperty;
```

Comment: Sorry I think you have misinterpreted my question.     I am getting the username through AD, not from the SQL database.. What I want to do is have something basically like  string colour = 'Select colour from table where username = @username'   I know this isn't how its done, but it demonstrates what i'm trying to do

Comment: So is your question about how you *get* the data, or how you get the data *to your web page*

Comment: No, i've done that..   From AD I get the username.. so mgreen.  In my SQL table, i have Username | Colour.. So mgreen might have Red.  What I want to is, using the username i've captured from AD, go to the SQL table, and grab the Colour where the username is mgreen.. And assign it to a variable.. i.e. string UsersColour.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be a SQL query?  Are you using an O/R Mapper?

Comment: Whats an O/R Mapper?  And yes just an SQL query, but I don't know how to do it in the code.. i'm a newbie to asp

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, and don't take this offensively, but perhaps diving straight into writing a database-driven ASP.NET application isn't where you should be starting out.

I would attempt to learn more about the ASP.NET architecture first, learn the language well (VB.NET or C#), and start with something simpler.

With that said, and assuming you're going to attempt this anyway, what you are probably going to want to start out with [is ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET). Microsoft, through MSDN, provides a good page full of [ADO.NET Code Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

You'll have to define a connection string to your database, which may include specifying a third-party driver if you're using a database such as Sybase or MySql, or using an entirely different set of provider classes such as what you'd need for Oracle. Next you'll create a command containing your SQL query and execute the command. You need to consume the results and pull your value out of a result set, and then clean up the close the connection.

Check out the link; hopefully it will get you started. There are a ton of examples of ADO.NET sprinkled across the Interwebs, I'm sure you can find a working example.

If you want to skip ADO.NET and try something a bit more O/R mappery (and are using Microsoft SQL Server), you might be interested in checking out [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx).

Comment: I can do all that.. I'm not new to C#, just new to asp.. I'm using a dataset to populate and interact with some UI stuff, but wasn't sure what the accepted method was in regards to doing it with code.  I haven't played with LINQ yet (mostly .Net 2.0 stuff in the past) so i'll check that out.. also the O/R Mapper that you and Adam have mentioned.. Thanks for your help.